# How can I properly create invalid Vector3 in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optional-parameters

I often need to pass *invalid location* to functions that optionally can use location (eg. RTS unit action). But this does not compile:

```
public abstract void CastSpell(Spell spell, Vector3 targetLocation = null);
```

So how can I make a proper *invaid* Vector3 to determine invalid/"don't care" locations? I've seen things like vector with -999999 coordinates - but that's a nasty trick that might cause bugs (eg. on huge maps).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, I found there was two solutions. The first solution was to create a wrapper for the class.

```
Class Vector3Wrapper
{
    Vector3 vector;
}
```

Then I would simply set the Vector3Wrapper to null then if it wasnt null access its vector. A better method would be making it a Nullable type. A example is below.

**[http://unitypatterns.com/nullable-types/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150705212014/http://unitypatterns.com/nullable-types/)**

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Notice the added "?"
    Vector3? targetPosition;
 
    void MoveTowardsTargetPosition()
    {
        //First, check if the variable has been assigned a value
        if (targetPosition.HasValue)
        {
            //move towards targetPosition.Value
        }
        else
        {
            //targetPosition.Value is invalid! Don't use it!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer? I don't want you to lose a good answer for it being a link only answer.

Comment: I expanded it a bit, I just did not want to rewrite information off the site and claim it as my own.

Comment: +1. And don't worry, as long as you site it then it is all good.